# How to create directory in sd card while my app runs for first time and delete that directory while uninstalling app

Tags: android

I am building an app which takes image from camera capture and save the images in a directory in sd card. I need to create a directory under sd card or where the app installed. So that while user is uninstalling my app that directory which was created by my app,will be deleted automatically. How can i do this?

Comment: you might want to re-consider deleting files off the SD Card. Because If I took pictures with your app, I might be rather upset when I uninstall your app and all my pictures go away. (depending on what the pictures are of, etc.) Also, if you only want them as a 'cache' while your app exists, then https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir() using the 'cacheDir()' might be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new File(getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null), "pic.jpg");
```

this code creates a file in the directory of your app and gets deleted on uninstall